# Not able to convert string to json

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net, withings

i am getting measurements from withings and want to show them in graphs but not able to convert it to json. i also try `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myString)` using `Newtonsoft.dll`and simple

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer sr = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
sr.Serialize(myString);
```

but it is not converting.

My withings measurement string is as follows.

```
{
  "status": 0,
  "body": {
    "updatetime": 1392764547,
    "measuregrps": [
      {
        "grpid": 17945868,
        "attrib": 0,
        "date": 139984270,
        "category": 1,
        "measures": [
          {
            "value": 72,
            "type": 9,
            "unit": 0
          },
          {
            "value": 152,
            "type": 10,
            "unit": 7
          },
          {
            "value": 87,
            "type": 17,
            "unit": 0
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "grpid": 176587495,
        "attrib": 0,
        "date": 13915689,
        "category": 1,
        "measures": [
          {
            "value": 94,
            "type": 9,
            "unit": 0
          },
          {
            "value": 145,
            "type": 10,
            "unit": 0
          },
          {
            "value": 109,
            "type": 11,
            "unit": 0
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "grpid": 179262494,
        "attrib": 0,
        "date": 1391369607,
        "category": 1,
        "measures": [
          {
            "value": 77,
            "type": 9,
            "unit": 0
          },
          {
            "value": 121,
            "type": 10,
            "unit": 0
          },
          {
            "value": 87,
            "type": 11,
            "unit": 0
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "grpid": 179258492,
        "attrib": 0,
        "date": 1391171167,
        "category": 1,
        "measures": [
          {
            "value": 61,
            "type": 9,
            "unit": 0
          },
          {
            "value": 107,
            "type": 10,
            "unit": 0
          },
          {
            "value": 80,
            "type": 11,
            "unit": 0
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "grpid": 179089150,
        "attrib": 0,
        "date": 1391167537,
        "category": 1,
        "measures": [
          {
            "value": 69,
            "type": 9,
            "unit": 0
          },
          {
            "value": 112,
            "type": 10,
            "unit": 0
          },
          {
            "value": 67,
            "type": 11,
            "unit": 0
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "grpid": 179079661,
        "attrib": 2,
        "date": 1391164672,
        "category": 1,
        "measures": [
          {
            "value": 720,
            "type": 1,
            "unit": -1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "grpid": 17998560,
        "attrib": 2,
        "date": 146989672,
        "category": 1,
        "measures": [
          {
            "value": 284,
            "type": 4,
            "unit": -2
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens? Do you get an error message? have you tried a smaller/subset of your JSON?

Comment: no i didn't get error but the same output as input

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, you want to *deserialize* your json string, not serialize:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Withings.RootObject>(json);
```

---

```
public class Withings
{
    public class Measure
    {
        public int value { get; set; }
        public int type { get; set; }
        public int unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class Measuregrp
    {
        public int grpid { get; set; }
        public int attrib { get; set; }
        public int date { get; set; }
        public int category { get; set; }
        public List<Measure> measures { get; set; }
    }

    public class Body
    {
        public int updatetime { get; set; }
        public List<Measuregrp> measuregrps { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public int status { get; set; }
        public Body body { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myString)` takes an object an returns a string. If you want to turn a string into an object you want to use `Deserialize<T>(sting json)`. Given the arguments name in your sample is `myString` I would assume you're using the method wrong.

To deserialize you need an equivalent type like;

```
   public class myObject
   {
        public int status { get; set; }
        public Body body { get; set; } 
   } 
   public class Body
   {
            //other parameters ect
    }
```

Your object model needs to exactly match the json in order by `Deserialize<T>` to behave correctly.